# Is this a valid explanation for why the leading term $a_nx^n$ always eventually controls the polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

Since a polynomial has a finite number of coefficients, there is always some $x$ such that $|x|>n\cdot|\frac{a_i}{a_n}|$ for all $i$. If that inequality holds, then $x^n$ has more control over the other terms.

Now that doesn't prove anything but you probably get the point; based on the above explanation, does it seem like I understand the concept and intuition of why $a_nx^n$ always eventually controls the polynomial?

Someone explained it by saying that $\frac{x_n}{x_m}=x^{n-m}\to\infty$ if $x>m$, but I don't really understand what this is trying to say, I don't know calculus. But I mean I do kind of understand that $x^n$ grows faster than all the others as $x$ increases.

Comment: What do you want to say, exactly? Do you want to say that $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} p(x)=\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} a_n x^n$ (which loosely speaking means "the behavior at infinity is the same")? Do you want to say the stronger statement $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} p(x)/(a_n x^n)=1$? What's the actual goal?

Comment: i dont know calculus, so im not trying to understand polynomials in terms of limits right now. My goal is to understand why the leading term eventually controls the polynomial. Without calculus knowledge, is it enough to just understand that since there are a finite number of coefficients, they are bounded and hence eventually x will reach a value such that the leading term's absolute value is greater than all of the other's combined?

Comment: The question I am asking is what do you understand "eventually controls" to mean?

Comment: $p(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_0=a_n(x^n+\frac{a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0}{a_n})$, when $|x^n|>|\frac{a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0}{a_n}|$, i.e the "magnitude" of $x^n$ is greater, it has more "control" in the sum $x^n+\frac{a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0}{a_n}$, or it "outweighs" the effect of $\frac{a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0}{a_n}$, and from that point on, $a_nx^n$ "controls" the polynomial

Comment: The question as currently written is "does it seem like I understand the concept and intuition of why $a_nx^n$ always eventually controls the polynomial?" Yes, it seems like you probably understand the intuition (although if one were inclined to be more skeptical, the $n$ in the inequality is concerning). No, it does not seem like you understand the concept. Your most recent comment doesn't inspire much confidence; it only shifts the problem to defining the word "outweighs".

Comment: For instance, consider $f(x)=(x^2+2)+(x^2+1)$. Evidently the first "term" in this decomposition is always larger than the second. Should we say that $x^2+2$ controls $f$? (This is not a rhetorical question. Reasonable people could disagree on this; see [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation/), where indeed $f=O(x^2+2)$.) If your answer is no, you are likely to complain that I've split the leading term into two. Of course I cannot disagree, but it's not clear why that should be illegitimate.

Comment: If you truly want to understand why the leading term dominates (better word than "controls") the polynomial, you should look at larger $x$. Not just where the leading term becomes large enough to show that the polynomial can't be $0$ anymore, but millions, billions, trillions of times that size, so that the ratio $\dfrac{P(x)}{a_nx^n}$ is $1 + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ has a long list of leading zeros before the first non-zero digit is encountered. At this stage, $P(x)$ effectively is $a_nx^n$ with an extremely tiny correction. Larger $x$ just increase the imbalance.

Comment: @PaulSinclair can this also be explained by factoring into: $f(x)=a_nx^n(1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_nx}+\cdots+\frac{a_0}{a_nx^n})$? As you keep increasing $x$, the terms in $\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_nx}+\cdots+\frac{a_0}{a_nx^n}$ get smaller and smaller

Comment: It is a fuller explanation of my $1+\epsilon$ comment, so I wouldn't say "also", but, yes.